# Filter particular columns from pipe separated string using stream api or lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, filtering

Suppose I have a string/object having some data in pipe separated format as below

```
***Input:***
TIMESTAMP|COUNTRYCODE|RESPONSETIME|FLAG
1544190995|US|500|Y
1723922044|GB|370|N
1711557214|US|750|Y
```

I want to read this string/object and filter data based on particular columns names (assume for eg. TIMESTAMP and FLAG). 
And return/display the output as shown below-

```
***Output:***
TIMESTAMP|FLAG
1544190995|Y
1723922044|N
1711557214|Y
```

I tried using below code:

1. First i have required header names stored an array:

   ```
   headerArray[] = {TIMESTAMP, FLAG}
   ```
2. By comparing `headerArray[]` with first row of input, I got the index of specified column header in input:

   ```
   headerIndex[] = {0, 3}
   ```
3. Then tried using below code to filter and get the specified columns and values:

   ```
   return br.lines()
           .skip(1) // skip headers
           .map(s -> s.split("|"))
           .filter(a -> a[0] && a[3])
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Note: I have over a million lines of pipe separated values. And I want to return all filtered out column values in a single object. I suppose that not possible by returning value as list.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Not working as expected. It seems like returning random characters. something like "T|1|1".
And i'm not sure how to return it in an object and will it process millions lines and

Comment: `.filter(a -> a[0] && a[3])` surely doesn’t even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems:

first you should change `split`'s pattern to `\\|` and instead of filter you can you `map` to create new string.

```
 br.lines().skip(1) // skip headers
            .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
            .map(a -> String.join("|", a[0], a[3]))
            .collect(toList())
```

Comment: toList() - is this predefined method in java8 ? And I guess this returns list

Comment: Yes. it is and returns list!

Comment: List has a object size limitation. List size will be based on JVM heap size. So i doubt list will be able to handle millions of records. kindly correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @ShakthiRaj Why do you really want to process *millions of records* in memory(within JVM) in that case? It's not meaning/purposeful to attempt the task in such a manner. And what is the source of your input for these millions of entries to be processed?

Comment: @HadiJ Not really confident of a solution to post, but this seems much better a task using a regex/pattern rather than `split` and `join`. It just seems redundant at the very first look.

Comment: For now i'm using BufferReader to read the input.
And yes i agree JVM has restrictions, i did some trail and error with different collections to optimize performance and maximize the no. of lines processed.
For eg. using HashSet i processed 50K lines, but hashset doesnt allow duplicate values. Whereas List allows duplicate values, but only process 5k lines.

I'm just wondering how to process a million records using Java, there must be some way to do that even though it might effect the performance time.

Comment: I have also thought of processing in chunks or using cache in DB/in some services. But those are all new technologies, even in past people must have processed millions of records in JVM without any cache/services.

Comment: @ShakthiRaj please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429013/what-is-the-best-way-to-process-large-csv-files)

Comment: There is no reason why a list should “only process 5k lines”. Of course, that depends on the actual implementation used, as `List` is only an interface.

Comment: Thanks @HadiJ. I tried your code and it worked.
Instead of '.map(a -> String.join("|", a[0], a[3]))', created a function for dynamic a[] index join like '.map(a -> indexJoin())'

Is there any other way to make the a[] index dynamic.